# Web Inspector IOS9 safari blank

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to debugg my cordova app but when I go to open the web inspector I get blank screen with no content. I'm testing my app on ipad ios 9.2, OSX 10.10.5 , safari 9.1. I enable on the device the option web inspector and also javascript, I'm building the app from xcode 7.2.

[image: screen shot showing empty safari web inspector window]

Comment: does it happen every time you open the web inspector ? also did you try by opening the same by running the app in the simulator ?

Comment: yeah it happens all the time, I think is some bug on my version, I ask someone else to try and it doesn't happen for them. I'm trying to have 2 version of safari but still no luck

Answer (score 2):

In the device 
Open your device’s Safari settings and ensure that **Private Browsing is turned off**. Remote debugging will not work if Private Browsing is enabled.

Or Try the same thing in the 'Safari private browsing' on the mac
Which you can access from 'File' -> New Private Window

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18930141/4557505

Else try  close Safari, delete /Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db 
Ref:

Ref: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23500730#23500730

Comment: Deleting the Safari cache from my user's folder fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that cookies are allowed in your OS X Safari.